# Continuous user input calculator

Tags: java

so I'm trying to create a simple calculator program that have these features:

Continuously calculating user input depending on the operation

Exit the program when user inputs 'x' in any part of the program

So far, I'm able to just calculate 2 numbers but what I need is for it to keep going until the user presses or inputs 'x'.

Sample output I want would be like this:

```
Num 1: 5 
Operator: + 
Num 2: 5 
---------------
 Result: 10 

Operator: +
 Number 3: 10 
-------- 
Result: 20
```

and this keeps going until X is pressed

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int result = 0;
        String operator;
        boolean isNumber;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        do {

            System.out.println("Enter First Number: ");
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                num1 = scanner.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;
            } else {
                System.err.println("Not a valid number");
                isNumber = false;
                scanner.next();
            }
        } while (!(isNumber));


        System.out.println("Enter Operator ");
        operator = scanner.next();
        while (!operator.equals("+") && !operator.equals("-") && !operator.equals("*") && !operator.equals("/")) {
            System.err.println("Invalid operator. Enter Correct Operation:");
            operator = scanner.next();
        }

        do {

            System.out.println("Enter Second Number: ");
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                num2 = scanner.nextInt();
                isNumber = true;
            } else {
                System.err.println("Invalid Input. Enter Correct Number");
                isNumber = false;
                scanner.next();
            }
        } while (!(isNumber));


        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                addition(num1, num2, result);
                break;

            case "-":
                subtraction(num1, num2, result);
                break;

            case "*":
                multiplication(num1, num2, result);
                break;

            case "/":
                division(num1, num2, result);
            case "x":
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void addition(int num1, int num2, int result) {
        result = num1 + num2;
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("RESULT:" + result);
    }

    public static void subtraction(int num1, int num2, int result) {
        result = num1 - num2;
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("RESULT:" + result);
    }

    public static void multiplication(int num1, int num2, int result) {
        result = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("RESULT:" + result);
    }

    public static void division(int num1, int num2, int result) {
        result = num1 / num2;
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println("RESULT:" + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change your logic for handling input completely in my opinion. You need one common loop for both numbers and operators and you need to have the code determine if it is a number or an operator. Remember that after the first _number, operator, number_ sequence has been given the flow will be _operator, number_ since you have the first number in the `result` variable already

Comment: I would also suggest your methods for performing the operations should return a value rather than having the `result` as an argument, `pubic static int division(int num1, int num2) { return num1 / num2; }`. I also would consider using double instead of int throughout the code.